# How to increase the maximum size of adjacent list in c++?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, memory-management

I am using the Dijkstra algorithm in this [webpage](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-7-dijkstras-algorithm-for-adjacency-list-representation/). Recently I find out that if the number of the vertices exceeds 60000 in the graph, the system will respond with "core dumped" when adding new edge information as node into adjacent list.

Here is the excerpt of adjacent list in the original program:

```
// A structure to represent a node in adjacency list
struct AdjListNode
{
    int dest;
    int weight;
    struct AdjListNode* next;
};

// A structure to represent an adjacency liat
struct AdjList
{
    struct AdjListNode *head;  // pointer to head node of list
};

// A utility function to create a new adjacency list node
struct AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(int dest, int weight)
{
    struct AdjListNode* newNode =
            (struct AdjListNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct AdjListNode));
    newNode->dest = dest;
    newNode->weight = weight;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

And here is the code of graph and adding new edge

```
// A structure to represent a graph. A graph is an array of adjacency lists.
// Size of array will be V (number of vertices in graph)
struct Graph
{
    int V;
    struct AdjList* array;
};

// A utility function that creates a graph of V vertices
struct Graph* createGraph(int V)
{
    struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->V = V;

    // Create an array of adjacency lists.  Size of array will be V
    graph->array = (struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList));

     // Initialize each adjacency list as empty by making head as NULL
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
        graph->array[i].head = NULL;

    return graph;
}

// Adds an edge to an undirected graph
void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest, int weight)
{
    // Add an edge from src to dest.  A new node is added to the adjacency
    // list of src.  The node is added at the begining
    struct AdjListNode* newNode = newAdjListNode(dest, weight);
    newNode->next = graph->array[src].head;
    graph->array[src].head = newNode;

    // Since graph is undirected, add an edge from dest to src also
    newNode = newAdjListNode(src, weight);
    newNode->next = graph->array[dest].head;
    graph->array[dest].head = newNode;
}
```

And for your reference, here is the main function that I test

```
int main()
{
    int V = 100000;
    struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V);
    for(int i=0;i<V/2;i++)
        for(int j=i+1;j<V;j++)
            addEdge(graph, i, j, i+j);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're running out of memory, no?

Comment: There is no issue [here when using `std::list`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a2a176782acf771)

Comment: you should try either or both:

* refine your algorithm to be more memory effecient
* increase malloc limit

Comment: This is tagged as C++.  Use `std::list` or `std::forward_list` and forget the `malloc` stuff.  Even [100,000 nodes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ade97d3da9d14ff) gives no issue.

Comment: This code is not the most modern c++ and I would heed the advices given here. Nevertheless, the code has no big issues and there is no reason it should run out of memory sooner as a linked list. I would bet my money on an error in the code creating the graph, but we cannot see it here (so please add it!)

Comment: It uses more than 13GB memory size when number of nodes exceeds 60000. @ead You're right. The core dump happens when adding new edge information as node to the adjacent list. I will post the code of building the graph later

Comment: actually what I meant was the code which build the graph something like `int V = 9; struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V); addEdge(graph, 0, 1, 4);` without it nobody can know, what you are doing.

Comment: @ead Sorry for misunderstanding. I have added the main function in the post

Comment: All the code posted is C code, not C++ code.  If you're using C, you should tag this as C, not C++.

Comment: The code you linked to is not C++ code.  It uses *Variable Length Arrays*, and those are not standard C++.  The page says `C / C++ code` which doesn't exist.  It is purely `C` code and is patently **not** C++ code.  Maybe a better exercise would be to take that code and actually change it to use C++ containers like `std::list` and `std::vector`.

Comment: (_If_ sticking to C, consider a `typedef struct AdjListNode Adjacency;`. Old school would avoid one level of indirection using `struct Graph
{
    int V;
    struct AdjList vertices[];
};`. With a `next`-parameter to `newAdjListNode()`, the guts of `addEdge()` collapses to `graph->vertices[src].head = newAdjListNode(dest, weight, graph->vertices[src].head);
    graph->vertices[dest].head = newAdjListNode(dest, weight, graph->vertices[dest].head);`.)

Comment: _If_ the graph was static, you could use arrays of `typedef struct
{
    int dest;
    int weight;
} Edge;` instead of linked lists, for (2×)8 bytes per edge.

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to add almost 4*10^9 edges to the graph. Every edge (`AdjListNode` - object) needs 16 byte on a 64bit machine. We are also talking about at least 64GB, this is a lot.

However, every call of `malloc(sizeof(struct AdjListNode))` costs more than just 16 byte: there are some overhead for managing the elements on the heap and the system concedes more than 16 byte with every request for memory. On my system I needed 2GB for 4*10^7 edges, i.e. ca. 50 byte per edge.

Anyway, you will be out of memory at some point of  the program execution and `malloc` will return 0 in this part of your code:

```
struct AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(int dest, int weight)
{
    struct AdjListNode* newNode =
            (struct AdjListNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct AdjListNode));
    //newNode is NULL if there is no memory!
    newNode->dest = dest; //BOOM! segmentation error due to newNode==NULL
    ....
```

As you can see, the program will crash because of the NULL-pointer dereferencing.

I guess for every implementation, there is a limit of problem size for which it works. And the limit of this implementation is well bellow 4*10^9 edges.

As for your question: If you want to use less memory you should avoid allocating many different objects - it is better to put them into a continuous memory one after each other.  For this `std::vector` is a good choice if you use C++ (but your code is pure C).